# Apache/Passenger/RoR Slow - But Why

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, apache2, passenger

I am running Ubuntu (64Bit) with Apache 2.2.17, Passenger 3.0.11, Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.6

When accessing the web page (index.html) on my webpage the request takes ages to complete, somewhere around 30 second in extreme cases.

The server has plenty of memory available (top shows more than 4GB free), the Apache processes (there are 10 of them) each show 0% CPU in top and the load is also almost 0 and there are hardly any DB accesses as I cache most of the things with memcached.

The log files of Apache as well as Rails do not show any errors, on the contrary the render times shown in the RubyOnRails log file show excellent values (<100 ms).

So where to go from here?

Comment: I forgot to mention that i am using HTTPS, in case that has an impact here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The performance issue has been keeping me busy for all these days. I believe I have nailed it down to Apache configuration: KeepAliveTimeout, it was set to a very high value (90), can't think why it was set that high, must have been a typo. 
My understanding of KeepAliveTimeout is that the Apache process gets locked to the client for 90 seconds, even if the client isn't issuing any further requests, hence when traffic picks up (which it did on that day when performance was significantly reduced, page visits more than tripled)  all Apache processes are busy waiting for the KeepAliveTimeout, while blocking all new requests coming in. This would also explain why the system was not showing much load at all, it was just sitting there waiting. I reduced the value down to 10, if traffic picks up I'll probably drop it to 5.

Answer (score 2):

Is the first request slow or all requests slow? Passengers shutdown after a given time interval. So intermittenly requests (requests with sufficient time span in between) will allow passengers to shutdown (only to be restarted at next request.

Passenger does the autoshutdown BY DESIGN. This is so because on a shared environment, there might be other user's apps. If your app is idle for a while, then the resources can be transferred to other people's app.

If you are on a tight budget and you have multiple apps hosted on the same server, then passenger is a great solution.

If you have only ONE app in your server which you control, then please reconfigure Passengers to NOT shutdown (if that indeed is your problem).

You can do "passenger-status" to see how many passengers are currently running and available for taking requests.

The configuration to ensure that Passengers stay up is PassengerMinInstances and PassengerPoolIdleTime.

Comment: Each request is slow, I guess I didn't express myself correctly. I use Safari's Web Inspector to show the time needed for the HTTP requests. When opening the web page it gets index.html and various other CSS, JS and images. It is the very first of these requests, the one getting index.html that takes ages. All subsequent ones get delieverd within the expected time.

Comment: Right in the first request, you have to account for the time that Passenger takes to load up all of rails. Subsequent calls have Rails loaded already but the first one takes extra time. Passenger wakes up on the first request if it was sleeping (and it sleeps automatically after a predefined idle time).

Comment: I have PassengerMinInstances set to 3. So there is typically always an  idle instance around.

Comment: What is the PassengerPoolIdleTime? I seriously think the reason might be the startup time taken by Passenger on the first "wake up" call. Have you tried running "unicorn" or "thin" on the server? It also occurred to me that on some machines with limited memory, choosing to go with 64bit OS was not a good one, but it seems to me that your server has ample memory.

Comment: My PassengerPoolIdleTime is 1200 and my server has 8GB. It's got to be somewhere else, question is how to locate the root cause?

Comment: I'm sorry I finally understand that "each" request that hits rails is slow i your app. Since CSS/JS probably get served out by Apache directly the requests that all slow are the ones which hit rails. Now since the Idle time is 1200 (20 mins), passengers should not get shutdown for at least that much time. What do see as the log start time in rails and the apache access log? what is the lag there? can you curl from within your production box to hit the rails server and how slow/fast is that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing it through a 'fake domain name' (added to your `/etc/hosts` file)?

If so, do

```
service avahi-daemon stop
```

At least that's what worked for me on ubuntu 10.10 :)

For some reason a DNS lookup is made on each and every request you do to the server, and when the domain doesn't exists, it times out ...

Comment: I can ping the domain name shown in /etc/hosts file from other computer, so it's not "fake". Is that what you mean?

Comment: How do you access the app? Is it a real,registered  domain name?

Comment: Yes it is. Registered Domain, proper SSL certificate (if that makes a difference).

Comment: Hmm ok... I'd start by trying without HTTPS to see it that makes a difference. Also try to get the page using `wget` to see where you're losing time. Could be the connection to the server, or donwloading the response file ...